# OS X Windows Style AppBar

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to create an AppBar in OS X like you can in Windows? As another possibility can you reserve desktop/screen space like the dock bar does? Eg. When you maximize a window it will not cover the dock bar.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The Dock is similar to the AppBar and already exists.

Comment: I would like to have a sliver on the left side of the screen that allows people to control modes within an application. AppBars in windows allow you to create additional bars using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "controlling modes within an application"? Are you speaking of UI modes?

Comment: The application has a few pseudo fullscreen modes that can be controlled via the "Sidebar" that will be used on Meeting Room computers.

Basically I just want to have a "Sidebar" that other applications know not to cover when they are maximized.

Comment: -[NSScreen visibleScreen] returns a rectangle that excludes the menu bar and Dock. The trouble is that you've no way to modify this rectangle yourself. Even if you could, it's still a matter of a given window's controller choosing to respect that rectangle (and often, that doesn't happen). On top of that, a user can drag a portion of a window outside of that rectangle. It would appear that you're fighting a losing battle here. While new UI conventions are always worthy of consideration, I think it best in this case that you leave the Windows conventions to your Windows users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an "always-on-top" window by setting the window's level to something high via `[NSWindow setLevel:]`. (I think that `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` is currently the highest level.) This will keep it above other applications, if I recall correctly. However, I don't know of a way to carve out a section of the screen that other apps will obey.